# Angular - Services are not exported from a custom library to consumer project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, gulp

I build an angular library, that has two types of services (along with components/modules)

- Services private to the library, used for internal functionality that should not be available to the consumer project (let's call them **internal**)
- Services that should be used to move data between the library's components/modules and the consumer project.(let's call them **external**)

Both cases are a bit problematic and thus they get one section each.
Sorry for the long post.

---

*Note* Every library component is also a module, in order to selectively import what is needed, and not the whole library

---

### Internal Services

They are packed with the module using the `forRoot()` method as shown bellow:

```
export class TestModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestModule,
      providers: [ TestService ]
    }
  }
}
```

and then in the consumer projects `app.module`

`TestModule.forRoot()` is used.

Everything here works fine. 
The weird thing is when I use the selector of the component packed in the `TestModule` as a view child I can access externally a private property.
Here are some snippets to make it clearer what happens:

`<test-selector #testViewChild></test-selector>`

`@ViewChild('testViewChild') testViewChild;`

`this.testViewChild.testService.myTestValue = 'I was set in the test project'`

The last snippet is from the typescript file of the TestComponent in the exported in the TestModule

```
 constructor(private testService: TestService) {
    this.testService.myTestValue = 'I was set in the library';
  }
```

The actual service `myTestValue === 'I was set in the test project'`

**Anyone knows why this happens?!**

---

### External Services

Here things are weirder. As the library was first created it was bundled with `gulp`, but later it was switched to `webpack`. If I have everything straight in my mind, with gulp the services defined in the library had to be provided through the `app.module` of the consumer project and then there was this global service instance used both by the library and consumer project components.

After the switch to `webpack`, these services fail to be instantiated, throwing an error about the services having no providers, and although exported (in the `index.ts`) they can not be imported from the consumer `app.module` using `from 'test-library'`. A workaround was to set the path like `from '../../node_modules/test-library/......'`. But this just runs into more problems.

By using providers inside the library the service instances cannot be accessed from the consumer project (except with the hack above that feels utterly wrong).

So any ideas on what is going on?
Once again sorry for the long post.
And for a better and more descriptive title feel free to edit.

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: To some of the questions I think. It's been a while.
If you are stuck with something similar add to the comments here your question and I might be able to help